# onActivityResult is never called

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I want to pick a picture from gallery. I have an implicit intent and onActivityResult but it is never called.
 I have looked for possible solutions like this:

```
setResult(RESULT_LOAD_IMG, galleryIntent);
```

Here is my code in the AddQuestionActivity:

```
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;
    public static Intent galleryIntent;

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
                galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Toast is not the best way to debug the application. Use logs and place one inside success. Chances are setImageBitmap is not changing the image view bitmap leading you to believe the onActivityResult is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

please check your base activity `onActivityResult` if you have.

**RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1**

it might be possible if `1` is set in base activity onaActivitResult then `AddQuestionActivity` onactivityResult won't go forward

Comment: My baseActivity does not have onActivityResult but thanks for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

Update your code:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            }
        });
    }
```